# Consulta de HTML, no encuentra resultado

Tags: python

Tengo este script para buscar paginas web en funcion a un resultado, y no veo el problema, sin embargo no se consigue resultados aun cuando el codigo no arroja error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

search = input("introdusca su busqueda: ")
params = {"q": search} 
r = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search", params=params) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("ol",{"id":"b_results"})
print(results) 
links = results.findAll("li",{"class":"b_algo"})

for item in links:
    item_text = item.find("a").text
    item_href = item.find("a").attrs["href"]

   if item_text and item_href:
      print(item_text)
      print(item_href)
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: ¿Que no consigues? Tu pregunta no es clara.

Comment: Realizo una busqueda de una palabra,   y el resultado que tengo es que no encuentra nada relacionado a esa palabra.